# Is there any way to disable the default behavior of the Insert key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, remapping

I keep hitting the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key accidentally and it really annoys me.

Is there any way to disable it's default behavior, toggling insert/overwrite mode in editors?

Comment: What is the default behaviour, apart from toggling insert/overwrite mode in editors?

Comment: That's the default behavior. I want it to do nothing.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Go to *Keyboard Shortcuts* in *System settings*, then press Add button and insert a Name of your choice, say "DisableIns", and `true` as a harmless command then press Apply button.

Now, in the *Custom Shortcuts* section you will find an entry

```
DisableIns | Disabled
```

Click on `Disabled`, then perform your custom shortcut *Ins*. Press close, you're done.

Comment: I did not find a pre-made entry, but making a custom shortcut with the command `;` worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure it is the "right" way, but in my tests I could disable the behaviour of Insert using the following command:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 118 ="
```

If this works for you, you could put the assignment in a file `~/.Xmodmap`, i.e.

```
keycode 118 =
```

which should be loaded automatically at login. See questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/185345/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/193200/etc-x11-xmodmap-doesnt-work-for-ubuntu) for more information about local xmodmap configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Type `sudo nautilus` in Terminal. Then go to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and open `pc`. Then change this line:

```
key  <INS> {    [  Insert       ]   };
```

to

```
key  <INS> {    [  XF86Send     ]   };// Insert
```

Then run this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

in Terminal and restart Ubuntu.

This will replace `Insert` with `Send`. You can replace it with any other appropriate key. To see a list of keys run this:

```
xmodmap -pke
```

**Note**: A mistake in editing `pc`. eg inserting an inappropriate character, may corrupt Ubuntu.